# How to create trigger that creates a table to log errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm using SQL Server and I'm trying to create a trigger that prevents dropping of views and creates a separate error log table that stores the details: user, date/time, attempt type and view name which will be provided by the system.

So far I've got the trigger to prevent dropping of views but am not able to get the system to provide me with the data without hard coding it in.

```
create trigger TRG_PREVENT_VIEW_DROP
on database for DROP_VIEW
as
    print 'View dropping is prohibited!'
    print 'rollback transaction'
    rollback transaction
go
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using, and ideally the version, e.g. [SQL-Server-2016]

Comment: Not sure which data you want the "system to provide you" but you can get a lot of contextual information from the `EVENTDATA` object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Do you actually want to create an error log table? Or add a row to your existing error log table?